# Touch controls of android not detecting my X position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I have been 3 days trying to solve this problem but still nothing. I am working on a game where by using the touch screen of the phone, a ball would move to the X position of your finger when you touch the screen, and do something different when while holding your first finger, you tap with the second finger.

The phone does detect whether it is the first touch or the second touch, and the second does what it is supposed to do. But the first touch does not do what it is supposed to. I know it is detected, because I already tested it. But there must be some mistake with the way I am making the ball move.

This is my code.

I have tried using AddForce, but I don't want the ball to keep going after I release my finger. Also tried many types of touches, also tried using a Joystick, but after I release my finger, the ball keeps going (a little bit further).

```
 foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{

    if (touch.fingerId == 0)
    {    

            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0f;
            if (touchPosition.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 10, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }
            else if (touchPosition.x < transform.position.x)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 10, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            }

    }


    if (touch.fingerId == 1)
    {

        Accelerate();
    }
}
```

I would like the code to detect whether my finger is more to the left or more to the right of the ball, and move the player to the left or right accordingly. I am also trying to make it move "smoothly", not too fast, not too slow. And afterwards, if I move my finger without lifting the finger up, the ball would still follow it.

I have spent 3 days trying different ideas....I appreciate any help. Also already searched in many posts, and unity's documentation and forum. Also searched for youtube videos...but have not found nothing really useful.

edit. forgot to mention. This is exclusively for android at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your second else if statement you check your position against a ball object. Is this script not attached to the ball you are trying to move? This script is currently changing the transform.position of whatever GameObject it is attached to.

I'm going to do some assuming about that information, instead of:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 10, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Try:

```
ball.transform.position = new Vector3(ball.transform.position.x + 10, ball.transform.position.y, ball.transform.position.z);
```

As an additional sidenote, calling transform.position on an object can be an expensive call if it's made frequently. You're making 3 transform.position reads and a write in one line here. I would recommend caching your transform.position to a Vector3 and updating that variable's values in your logic, then re-assigning it to the transform at the end. Like this:

```
Vector3 ballPosition = ball.transform.position;
ballPosition.x = ballPosition.x + 10;
ball.transform.position = ballPosition;
```

---

### Update

It looks like you're using [Touch.fingerId](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html), which explicitly states:

> Touch.fingerId is not the same as "first" touch, "second" touch and so on. It is merely a unique id per gesture. You cannot make any assumptions about fingerId and the number of fingers actually on screen, since virtual touches will be introduced to handle the fact that the touch structure is constant for an entire frame (while in reality the number of touches obviously might not be true, e.g. if multiple tappings occur within a single frame).

Touch.fingerId doesn't actually tell you which finger it was. It's merely a reference. This is because the touches are read on every frame, and the order of the touches can differ between frames. I would recommend the following:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        //Move ball code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a mistake, I mean, I am actually refering to the transform component of the gameObject the script was attached to.
"ball" is a reference to the rigidBody of the gameObject that I was using to modify the velocity. At first, I refered to ball.transform.position."whatever" but then I corrected it, leaving accidentaly the one you noticed. Already corrected it but still not working... And thanks for the last tip! I did not know that was an expensive call

Comment: Are there any collidrs in the scene that could be preventing the ball from moving? I would recommend disabling the rigidbody and collider of the ball and see if the script works with those turned off.

Comment: Already tried, nothing different happened. The only colliders I have are some walls and the floor.
I tried using transform translate, to see if it moved. But something weird happens. If I press with one finger, nothing happens, but when I press with two fingers, first my second part of the code triggers (Accelerate()) and then the ball kind of goes from left to right super super super fast, left to right and right to left, and repeats super fast. And does the same until I release it...

Comment: You know what? I think this has something to do with you using fingerId. Let me modify this answer.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it was with the touch position? Maybe I shouldn't be comparing the touch position with the ball's position, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I gave an update. The current solution I provide can result in multiple "2nd" and "3rd" touches if you lift up your first finger and place it back down again. In order to get a first touch, there needs to be no touches on the screen. There's another way to get around this, but I assume you want your game to function where the touch is equal to the number of fingers on the screen at the moment of the touch.

Comment: That one was really interesting. But no....Still not working.

I also tried with something else. Instead of converting screenToWorld, I tried worldToScreen, by converting the ball's position to the user's finger pressed position. It kind of worked. Only that right now, for some reason, the ball is always like 10 pixels to the right the whole time from the finger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. Not sure if it is the best way, but it works.

```
 if (!accelerated)
    {

        Vector3 playerPosition = gameObject.transform.position;



        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {


            if (touch.fingerId == 0)
            {


                playerPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPosition);
                Vector2 touchPosition = touch.position;
                if (touchPosition.x -15 >= playerPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);

                }
                else if (touchPosition.x + 15 <= playerPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                }


            }


            if (touch.fingerId == 1)
            {

                Accelerate();
            }
        }




    }
```

Comment: Even though it works, it has many bugs. Many it has to do with what Erik says, about the ID.